# Как сделать изображение квадратным в Yii2?

Tags: yii2, изображения

И снова я с вопросами о Yii2.
На этот раз проблема с аватаром пользователя. Необходимо, чтобы он был **квадратный**.
Каким образом - не важно.

Если можно как-то прописать в rules, что можно грузить только квадратные изображения - отлично, подойдет, пусть эту проблему решает пользователь)) Если ее можно обрезать - тоже отлично.

Но пока мои поиски в гугле увенчались находкой миллиона библиотек для обрезки изображений, однако они не гарантируют квадрат, в них можно обрезать свободно.
Ну и хотелось бы, чтобы оригинал не грузился на сервер (или удалялся после этого).

Как сие можно реализовать?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/757/how-to-use-imagine-crop-thumb-effects-for-images-on-yii2/#hh3

Comment: Спасаете меня постоянно. Гигантское спасибо!) @Blacknife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря человеку выше был использован следующий код. Может новичкам тоже пригодится, так как до документации не все добираются.

В модельке формы подключаем библиотеку:

`use yii\imagine\Image;`

В этой же модельке в функции загрузки изображений:

```
Image::thumbnail('@webroot/uploads/avatars/'.$this->avatar->baseName . $time . '.' . $this->avatar->extension, 120, 120)
    ->save(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/uploads/avatars/'.$this->avatar->baseName . $time . '.' . $this->avatar->extension), ['quality' => 80]);
```

где `$this->avatar->baseName . $time . '.' . $this->avatar->extension`

новое имя изображения, состоящее из: базового имени загружаемой картинки(без расширения)+время(записанное в переменную ранее)+расширение.

В приведенном примере оригинал перезаписывается квадратной иконкой в одной и той же папке, а @webroot - вебрут текущего приложения (там где находится входной скрипт index.php), в моем случае просто папка web.